# Can someone explain this mysql code to me

Tags: mysql

This is a mysql code to print prime numbers less than 1000, but i couldn't understand it properly, can someone explain what is happening here.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NUMB SEPARATOR '&')
FROM (
  SELECT @num:=@num+1 as NUMB FROM
  information_schema.tables t1,
  information_schema.tables t2,
  (SELECT @num:=1) tmp
  ) tempNum
WHERE NUMB<=1000 AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @nu:=@nu+1 as NUMA FROM
            information_schema.tables t1,
            information_schema.tables t2,
            (SELECT @nu:=1) tmp1
            LIMIT 1000
        ) tatata
    WHERE FLOOR(NUMB/NUMA)=(NUMB/NUMA) AND NUMA<NUMB AND NUMA>1
)
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally speaking, we're here as volunteers to help others with specific problems, or specific things you are stuck on. Looking at the code, without the schema of the referenced tables makes giving a specific answer impossible,. It also looks like one of the worst ways I've seen to list prime numbers. It shouldn't even need tables for the calculations, maybe one table to store the results.

Comment: Quite frankly, this is not an easy query to follow for beginners. I'd have asked the same question if I was a beginner and this query was in front of me. I appreciate that OP is curious to understand how it works.

Comment: Harini, if you found the answer satisfactory, you can put closure to your question by marking the answer as accepted OR you can wait for more answers. It's your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down step by step.

**How many rows does information_schema.tables have?**

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables t1
-> 370
```

**How many rows does information_schema.tables, information_schema.tables have?**

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables t1, information_schema.tables t2
--> 370 * 370 = 136900
```

**What is := and tmp?**

```
(SELECT @num:=1) tmp
```

`SELECT @num:=1` means we are initializing a variable. `(SELECT @num:=1) tmp` means we are making a table out of that.

**What is tempNum table?**

```
SELECT @num:=@num+1 as NUMB
FROM
  information_schema.tables t1,
  information_schema.tables t2,
  (SELECT @num:=1) tmp
```

This is almost the same as t1, t2 combination (~137K records). However, what column is being pulled? The column is the variable we declared in tmp table and 1 is added to it. Starting number will be 2, then 3, and onwards.

**Why filter NUMB?**

Just focus on this part:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NUMB SEPARATOR '&')
FROM (
  SELECT @num:=@num+1 as NUMB FROM
  information_schema.tables t1,
  information_schema.tables t2,
  (SELECT @num:=1) tmp
  ) tempNum
WHERE NUMB<=1000
```

This would take just the first 1000 records from ~137K records starting from 2 and ending at 1000. `GROUP_CONCAT` makes the result `2&3&4&5...&1000`.

**What does tatata do?**

Just focus on this now.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @nu:=@nu+1 as NUMA
    FROM
        information_schema.tables t1,
        information_schema.tables t2,
        (SELECT @nu:=1) tmp1
    LIMIT 1000
) tatata
```

This acts similar to the tempNum but with a slight difference. The inner query selects numbers from 2 and takes 1000 items. That means, the last number is 1001. All those numbers are aliased in `tatata` virtual table.

**End game**

Focus on the this part:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT @nu:=@nu+1 as NUMA FROM
            information_schema.tables t1,
            information_schema.tables t2,
            (SELECT @nu:=1) tmp1
            LIMIT 1000
        ) tatata
    WHERE FLOOR(NUMB/NUMA)=(NUMB/NUMA) AND NUMA<NUMB AND NUMA>1
)
```

So, you know that tempNum has 2..1000. The query above says, get everything from tempNum as long as none of tatata's number can wholly divide tempNum.

- Let's say tempNum is 2
- Get all numbers from tatata less than 2. tatata doesn't have any number less than 2
- So, information in that subquery doesn't exist (NOT EXISTS is true)
- Extract 2

Next number

- tempNum is 3
- Get all numbers from tatata less than 3. That'd be just 2
- One by one, divide 3 with numbers found. We just found 2. So, divide 3 by 2. Was it a clean division? No.
- So, information in that subquery doesn't exist (NOT EXISTS is true)
- Extract 2

Next number

- tempNum is 4
- Get all numbers from tatata less than 4. That'd be just 2 and 3
- One by one, divide 4 with numbers found
- Did either 2 or 3 wholly divide 4? Yeah...2 divides 4 wholly.
- So, information in that subquery exists. It'd return 2 (NOT EXISTS is false)
- Do not extract 4

And on...

As you see, prime numbers are being extracted from tempNum. `GROUP_CONCAT` just takes the resulting prime numbers and connects them with `&` resulting in `2&3&5&7...`

Comment: Awesome. You are welcome to make the answer as accepted so that other users can find this question as solved.